# Getting crash when application is loading in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting a crash when app loads up with this error: `Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'Main' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set?` So, in `Main.Storyboard` I don't check `is initial view controller` because as you can see in my code I am doing it in my `AppDelegate`, but when app runs it crashes and stops on my `assertionFailure()` catch. Can anyone help me solve this? Thanks for the help. Also, I have inputted `LocationViewController` as my Storyboard ID with `Use storyboard id` unchecked. (I even checked it and still same error).

Here is my code:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    let window = UIWindow()
    let locationService = LocationService()
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let service = MoyaProvider<YelpService.BusinessesProvider>()
    let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()

       func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    jsonDecoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    service.request(.search(lat: 34.148000, long: -118.361443)) { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let response):
            let root = try? self.jsonDecoder.decode(Root.self, from: response.data)
            print(root)
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
    }

    let locationViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LocationViewController") as? LocationViewController
    locationViewController?.locationService = locationService
    window.rootViewController = locationViewController

    window.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
}
```

Comment: Wait, so does the code go into the .notDetermined case or the default case?

Comment: remove "Main" in the Main Interface field and it should work fine
and check this video it will help you start coding without using storyboard https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r696qMJidWI

Comment: You got it correct. It just go straight to `.default` and calls the `assertionFailure()`

Comment: AssertionFailure will always crash the app. I think your locationService status is not being initiated correctly.. Usually location services uses a delegate pattern in a view controller. Are you using a tutorial for this?

Comment: I have removed it from text field `Main` and it still crashes on `assertionFailure()`

Comment: Oh, so check in my services class `YelpService.BusinessesProvider` , right?

Comment: No, you are trying to grab the status of your LocationService. I don't know what class your LocationService is ( A link would be helpful which class you are using?). But what is happening is the status property is default by default.. so your code always goes to the assertionFailure.

Comment: Please see updated question.

Comment: I told you it's not related to the YelpService.businessprovider.. Anyways.. if you put the

  **let locationViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LocationViewController") as? LocationViewController
  locationViewController?.locationService = locationService
   window.rootViewController = locationViewController**

  into the default case, it should run.

Comment: inside `defaultCase` when I implement that - I get an error as `Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'`

Comment: Put your code from the .notDetermined, .denied, .restricted: into the default case

Comment: Please see updated question , It gives me errors when I apply like that.

Comment: You need the default case because your switch statement doesn't handle all cases. Put your code from the .notDetermine. denied.. into its default case

Answer (score 1):

Your app is crashing because your locationService.status is defaulting so it is always reaching assertionFailure().

*Use this function to stop the program, without impacting the performance of shipping code, when control flow is not expected to reach the call—for example, in the default case of a switch where you have knowledge that one of the other cases must be satisfied* 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1539616-assertionfailure

1) Find a way to fix your locationService.status

2) Bypass the switch statement

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    jsonDecoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    service.request(.search(lat: 34.148000, long: -118.361443)) { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let response):
            let root = try? self.jsonDecoder.decode(Root.self, from: response.data)
            print(root) <-- Console is printing nil here because your jsonDecoder failed.
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
    }

    let locationViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LocationViewController") as? LocationViewController
    locationViewController?.locationService = locationService
    window.rootViewController = locationViewController

    window.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

Comment: So, I dont need second switch statement.?

Comment: However, when I apply your code - it runs my app but in the console it says `nil`

Comment: You only need the second switch statement if you want to actually use the LocationService.status ( Which you are not using correctly)

See updated answer why you are getting nil

Comment: see updated question, I implement the same way as you do and shows `nil`. mhmm